# How to group_concat by name

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I got a pivot table:

```
      ID              Reference          Key               Value
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    01                  001             date                03/04/2009
    02                  001             shift               1st
    03                  001             station 1           Mark
    04                  001             station 2           John
    05                  001             station 2           Macy
    06                  002             date                04/04/2009
    07                  002             shift               2nd
    08                  002             station 1           John
    09                  002             Station 1           Drey
    10                  002             Station 2           Macy
```

I currently got a view that generates the following table (used group_concat and then group by date field):

```
    Date            shift             station 1                station 2
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    03/04/2009      1st                 Mark                   John, Macy
    04/04/2009      2nd                 John, Drey              Macy
```

And i would like to have:

```
    Operator          Date                Shift                 Station
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Mark             03/04/2009            1st                    1
    Macy             03/04/2009            1st                    2                
    Macy             04/04/2009            2nd                    2
    Drey             04/04/2009            2nd                    1
    John             03/04/2009            1st                    2
    John             04/04/2009            2nd                    1
```

Tx a lot!

Comment: Just amend your view to suit.

Comment: that`s the problem @Strawberry ... I really didnt find a way to do it! LOL

Comment: Perhaps you could normalize your data.

Comment: I`m afraid i cant do that, as the table is has much more keys than i stated here. Would be too much columns...

Comment: There's no obligation to use an RDBMS. Flat files are fun too. If you do want to use an RDBMS then at least provide a column/table per data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that I'm not actually advocating this as a solution. Instead, you should normalize your design, particularly in regards the m:n relationship between shifts and operators, and also to reflect the different data types which are (or should be) involved...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS eav_hell;

CREATE TABLE eav_hell
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,entity INT NOT NULL
,attribute VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
,value VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO eav_hell (entity,attribute,value) VALUES
(1,'date','03/04/2009'),
(1,'shift','1st'),
(1,'station 1','Mark'),
(1,'station 2','John'),
(1,'station 2','Macy'),
(2,'date','04/04/2009'),
(2,'shift','2nd'),
(2,'station 1','John'),
(2,'Station 1','Drey'),
(2,'Station 2','Macy');

SELECT a.operator
     , b.date
     , b.shift
     , b.station
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN attribute IN ('station 1','station 2') THEN value END operator FROM eav_hell ) a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT entity
            , 1 station
            , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'date' THEN value END) date
            , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'shift' THEN value END) shift
            , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN attribute= 'station 1' THEN value END) names
         FROM eav_hell
        GROUP 
           BY entity
        UNION
       SELECT entity
            , 2 
            , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'date' THEN value END) date
            , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'shift' THEN value END) shift
            , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN attribute= 'station 2' THEN value END) 
         FROM eav_hell
        GROUP 
           BY entity

     ) b
    ON FIND_IN_SET(a.operator,b.names) > 0;

    +----------+------------+-------+---------+
    | operator | date       | shift | station |
    +----------+------------+-------+---------+
    | Mark     | 03/04/2009 | 1st   |       1 |
    | John     | 04/04/2009 | 2nd   |       1 |
    | John     | 03/04/2009 | 1st   |       2 |
    | Macy     | 03/04/2009 | 1st   |       2 |
    | Macy     | 04/04/2009 | 2nd   |       2 |
    | Drey     | 04/04/2009 | 2nd   |       1 |
    +----------+------------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: It worked just the way i expected. Thank u very much !